# Need to clear Google OAuth cache?

Tags: php, oauth, callback, google-oauth

I set up the Google OAuth with Hybridauth and it works from my development folder e.g. http://example.com/dev and callback is located at http://example.com/dev/callback.php

Now I want to move the dev folder to the production folder e.g. http:/example.com/backend and callback is changed to http://example.com/backend/callback.php

I changed the Authorized redirect URIs from Google console, but Google keeps the old callback link when I do log in.

Is it necessary to clear cache from Google or wait for an amount of time to let Google update the changes?

```
$config = [ 'callback' => 'example.com/backedn/callback.php',
            'providers' => [ 'Google' => [ 'enabled' => true, 
                             'keys' => [ 'id' => 'xxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com', 
                                         'secret' => 'xxxxxxx', ], 
                             'scope' => 'email', ], ], ];
```

Comment: Please include your code.

Comment: $config = [
    'callback' => 'http://example.com/backedn/callback.php',
    'providers' => [

        'Google' => [
            'enabled' => true,
            'keys' => [
                'id'     => 'xxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com',
                'secret' => 'xxxxxxx',
            ],
            'scope' => 'email',
        ],

    ],
];

Above is the setting

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for my careless mistake as I call the old script from the popup

```
function auth_popup( provider ){
            // replace 'path/to/hybridauth' with the real path to this script
            var authWindow = window.open('http://example.com//dev/callback.php?provider='+provider, 'authWindow', 'width=600,height=400,scrollbars=yes');
            return false;
        }
```